# extracting words from dictionary-python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have some words and its meaning in a dictionary.I need to extract the meaning alone if I give the word.(For example,herd certain animals of the same species). How can I extract the meaning for a particular word?please help

living_thing           **animate_thing**
pigfishes                  **animal**
if i give pigfishes it should print animal

Comment: Could you show us an example of such dictionary?

Comment: Show your data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('file.txt') as myfile:
    d = dict(line.rstrip().split(None, 1) for line in myfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not a dictionary, that's just simply some text from a file. You can make a dictionary from that though:

```
d = {}
with open('file.txt') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        line = line.rstrip('\n').strip()
        d[line[0]] = line[1]
```

Then to access the dictionary normally, you would do:

```
print d['phyllotaxes']
```

Comment: but the code is just for looping through the words in the list right? how to get the corresponding meaning for a word?

Comment: @PrabhaNatarajan the for-loop is going through each line in the file. We are using it to create the dictionary you can use to access the meanings